# Administration of Covid Vaccine for Small Children in the EU

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, pediatrics

Is there a way to see the progress of the administration of Covid vaccines for small children (age under five) in the EU?

It is not easy to find all information in the usual news sources.

Maybe there is a website that shows the status for the different possible vaccines (Moderna, BioNtech, etc.).

Comment: This [Reuters article](https://theconversation.com/covid-vaccines-for-children-under-five-what-parents-need-to-know-183994) seems to indicate that there isn't an approved vaccine for the under 5s (as of 1st June '22). The  [official tracker](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/publications-data/covid-19-vaccine-tracker) doesn't disaggregate the under 60s in the totals, and the by-week summary lumps everyone under 18 together. You might need to wait a while for any figures to surface and get an answer.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I know that there is no approved one until now. But the FDA is in the process of approving, and at least Moderna has handed in documents to the EU for admission of their vaccine. It would be great if there is a web page (from the EU, or maybe from some university or society) which tracks the progress regarding the status of the vaccines for small children.

Comment: @JFabianMeier In most European countries, it is possible to get younger children vaccinated by compassionate use or off-label use. This is entirely legal, but there is a shift of responsibility of damages from the state/pharmaceutical company towards the doctor. Meaning i.e. if the child should theoretically suffer from long term consequences of the vaccine, you would need to sue the doctor, not the state/vaccine producer. Nonetheless this is a quite common way of vaccinating under 5 years old (and off-label usage is very common as well because there can't possible be EMA approval for every

Comment: [cont'd] drug for every possible indication, these approval studies/processes cost billions of moneys and if it works for patients xyz, usually everyone assumes it also works for patients zyx.

Comment: @Narusan Thank you for the useful information. That said, I guess that we are only one or two months away from an EMA approval, but it would be great to find out more about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site seems to give a reasonable overview:

https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/human-regulatory/overview/public-health-threats/coronavirus-disease-covid-19/covid-19-latest-updates

On 10th May the review for Spikevax started. No news for BioNtech.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The question asks for a website to monitor the progress.